# Image Maps name attribute with XHTML+RDFa 1.0 doctype

Tags: xhtml, imagemap, rdfa

After searching the other questions none have answered the specific issue I have.

We recently made the move to include Google's Rich Snippets to our site which involved a DocType change from XHTML 1.0 to XHTML+RDFa 1.0.

Now the issue is we use image maps on our site and the XHTML+RDFa states the 'name' attribute is invalid and fails validation. Removing the name attribute allows validation but prevents chrome/safari from being able to use the image map.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the id attribute in place of the name attribute. Make sure the id values are an exact case-sensitive match. If that doesn't work, then it looks like a webkit bug.

Comment: Yeah, it had both name and id being exactly the same, W3C validator said the name attribute is invalid with the doctype so I simply removed it. The id attribute works fine in my firefox but not on older ones or webkit based browsers.

I'm debating just putting name back in and ignoring W3C :(

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a solution to this so I had to add back the ID and Name attributes.

It's no longer W3c valid but works in all browsers. Not an ideal solution but works which is more important.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute "id" instead of "name" it happens to me and it works fine.

Regards

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/name-attribute-is-obsolete-what-is-the-correct-behavior-when-dealing-with-ancho